# Delete entire row if cells in specific range are all empty

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create a macro that would delete an entire row if all the cells in specific range (B to K in each of the 10 rows) are all empty. I tried the following:

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim rng As Range

For i = 1 To 10
Set rng = Range("B" & i, "K" & i).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
rng.EntireRow.Delete
Next i
```

If there are more following lines with empty cells, let's say 1 and 2, it deletes row 1 and move row 2 instead of the deleted one, so it becomes row 1. Then it skips the moved row, because i always increases so it never checks row 1 again. Is there any way to check if the row that was just deleted is really non-empty before moving to the next i?

Btw: I am using Excel 2013.

Comment: When deleting, loop backwards.

Comment: You need to loop backwards. `For i = 10 To 1 step -1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using the Special Cells, why not just use `CountA()`?

```
Sub t()
Dim i&

For i = 10 To 1 Step -1
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("B" & i, "K" & i)) = 0 Then
        Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

That way, you can avoid any errors in case there's no blanks.  Also, when deleting rows, it's recommended to start at the end, then `Step -1` to the beginning.

Edit:

Try this as well, it may be quicker:

```
Sub T()
Dim rng As Range

Set rng = Range("B1:K10") ' Since you're going to loop through row 1 to 10, just grab the blank cells from the start
rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Select ' Just to show you what's being selected. Comment this out in the final code
rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

I recommend stepping through that with F8 first, to see how it works.  In the range `B1:K10`, it will first select all rows where there's a blank cell.  Then, it'll delete those rows.

Comment: This solution seems to work except I still get one empty row for unknown reason - I made sure the cells are empty but it still skips that row. I will try to sort it out. Thank you for the solution. I tried to vote up your solution , but I do not have enough reputation to do so :(

Comment: @dusky3 - What row remains empty?  Can you put some sample data in your OP perhaps? (Copy/pasted is preferred over a screenshot, but whatever you can provide is appreciated).  I have an alternate idea that I'll edit into my OP.

Comment: **It was my fault, it works like a charm. Thank you @BruceWayne!**

Comment: @dusky3 you should see a checkmark below the 1 at top left. Consider checking that.